# Two different third party libraries use the same library with different versions

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, getstream-io, clevertap

We have two different third party libraries in our project. The problem both uses ExoPlayer with different versions. If the version of the ExoPlayer in my main project is bigger than 2.10.0 [Get Stream Chat SDK](https://github.com/GetStream/stream-chat-android) having a crash. Vice versa If the version is lower than 2.10.0 [Clever Tap SDK](https://developer.clevertap.com/docs/clevertap-sdks) having a crash. Gradle is choosing the latest version all the time. Is there a solution for this? For example, Can I use ExoPlayer 2.9.6 in Get Stream Chat SDK and ExoPlayer 2.12.0 in Clever Tap.

Comment: I meet problem very like this, but with a different third-party library - protobuf. Have you sovled your problem? Would you share your solution?

Comment: We reported the crash. The company which has a lower version of the exo player has updated the exo player. Even If they hadn't updated we would have updated the version in open-source SDK.

Comment: Hey @Harun Did you find the solution

Comment: We were not able to find a solution to choose an appropriate library version depending on the library.  Updating libraries looks like the best solution.